# Otimizar o movimento do marcador no Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estrou trabalhando com uma aplicação onde eu adiciono um *Marker* no mapa, seto ele como :

```
markUser.draggable(true);
```

Porém quero otimizar esse método, para mexer o marcador é necessário segurar durante um tempo, quero com um único clique poder arrastá-lo e que ele fique bem embaixo do dedo da pessoa e não acima ou abaixo como acontece.
Como por exemplo o aplicativo de Taxis, 99táxis.

Comment: E o que seria "otimizar"?

Comment: Como disse na pergunta quero com um único clique sem precisar fazer um longo clique, mover o marcador.

Comment: Ah, verdade! Quando li tinha entendido outra coisa. Não sei te dizer com certeza, mas acho que não é possível alterar este funcionamento.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada nesse [projeto](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/). Eles reimplementaram o uso do *marker* com *drag and drop*.

Outra opção é, implementar o método `onMapClick` da interface `OnMapClickListener` e nele você adicionar um *marker*. Dê uma olhada nesse [link](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/11/implement-a-draggable-marker-using-google-maps-android-api-v2/). Repare que a adição do *marker* está no `LongClick`, mas creio que nada impeça você de implementar isso no `Click` ao invés de `LongClick`.